# sql column names with single quotes

Tags: mysql

I've a table the includes two columns ID and age. When view the table, the columns names are in single quotes. That's, 'ID', 'AGE'.

If I tried to do a simple select statement for ID:

```
SELECT ID FROM table1
```

I'll be getting an error message of "invalid identifier 'ID' "

What's the solution here?

Comment: Can you script out the create table? The format looks correct...

Comment: "When view the table" -- view how exactly?

Comment: Actually this is in Snowflake, and there's an option to view the table. Unfortunately, I'm dont have the create table as I'm not the one who created it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! What makes you think that a Snowflake question should have a `mysql` tag? It's not, AFAICS, derived from MySQL. Is there a CLI client to Snowflake? There must be a way of getting the `CREATE TABLE...` statement - otherwise, you're flying blind (and so are we...). But, as mentioned elsewhere, using anything but [a-zA-Z0-9_] for table names is a disaster waiting to happen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is *not* the case, or you're going to get *tons* of problems down the line.
It's a Bad Idea to have *any* kind of "special" character in column names and single quotes would be just *mind-bendingly* difficult to work with.

Try this:

```
select `'ID'` from table1 ;
```

(That's Back-Tick, Single-Quote, capital-Eye, capital-Dee, Single-Quote, Back-Tick.)

If that *does* work (and I really, *really* hope it doesn't), then go find out who *created* this table and give them a damned good kicking!

If it *doesn't* work, then run *this* command and send us the output from it:

```
show create table table1 \g
```

Comment: `... and give them a damned good kicking!` - LOL! +1!

Comment: Thank you! Fixed the way the table was created and got rid of ' '!